# Questions regarding matrices and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

**Information:**

Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ be a matrix and $\boldsymbol{A}^H$ be the Hermitian/conjugate transpose of that matrix, with the formal definitions
$$\bigg(\boldsymbol{A}^H \bigg)_{ij}=\overline{\boldsymbol{A}_{ji}} \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \boldsymbol{A}^H=\big( \overline{\boldsymbol{A}} \big)^T = \overline{\boldsymbol{A}^T}$$
One interesting property of the conjugate transpose is that if $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ is a square matrix then
$$\det(\boldsymbol{A}^H)=\overline{\det(\boldsymbol{A})}$$

**Questions:**

***P1.*** Let $\boldsymbol{A}(x)$ be a matrix function such that $\boldsymbol{A}(x) \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$, and let $\boldsymbol{A}^\delta(x)$ be a matrix derived from $\boldsymbol{A}(x)$ such that
$$\det(\boldsymbol{A}^\delta(x)) = - \det(\boldsymbol{A}(x)) $$

*Q1.* What does this operation do to the matrix, and how can we find $\boldsymbol{A}^\delta(x)$, for any matrix $\boldsymbol{A}(x)$? What is the formula?

*Q2.* Are there any conditions that need to be applied to the matrix?

***P2.*** Is there a formula for the operation $\Sigma_n$, such that
$$\det(\boldsymbol{A}^\Sigma_n(x))= \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\det(\boldsymbol{A}^\delta(x))$$

**What I've tried**

Since multiplication is commutative, there are more than one matrices $\boldsymbol{A}^\delta(x)$ such that $\det(\boldsymbol{A}^\delta(x)) = - \det(\boldsymbol{A}(x))$.

I've tried a $2$-by-$2$ matrix
$$ A(x)=
\begin{pmatrix}
  f_{11}(x) & f_{12}(x)\\ 
  f_{21}(x) & f_{22}(x)
\end{pmatrix}$$
has the solutions
$$ A^\delta(x)=
\begin{pmatrix}
  f_{21}(x) & f_{22}(x)\\ 
  f_{11}(x) & f_{12}(x)
\end{pmatrix}
or
\begin{pmatrix}
  f_{12}(x) & f_{22}(x)\\ 
  f_{11}(x) & f_{21}(x)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
there are more of course with the same format.

A general solution will surely involve the formula
$${\displaystyle \det(A)=\sum _{\sigma \in S_{n}}\left(\operatorname {sgn}(\sigma )\prod _{i=1}^{n}a_{i,\sigma _{i}}\right).}$$

**Remark:** One MSE user pointed out: If $n$ is odd, i.e we can write it as $=2k+1$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\boldsymbol{A}^\delta= - \boldsymbol{A}$ is a viable solution since
$$\det(\boldsymbol{A}^\delta_{n \times n})= (-1)^n \det(\boldsymbol{A}) = (-1)^{2k+1}\det(\boldsymbol{A}) = -\det(\boldsymbol{A})$$

Comment: There are _many_ operations on matrices that negate the determinant: for example, swapping any two rows and columns will negate the determinant. Are you looking for a single operation $A^\delta$?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a single operation $A^\delta$, one with only one solution for any $n$, since there'd be obtained many more solutions by simply swapping the rows.

Comment: @Darius It is not clear what you mean by "an operation with only one solution for any $n$"

Comment: @Darius I think the point of the question is that we are not meant to know exactly what $A^\delta(x)$ looks like, only that it is one of the many operations that result in a change in the sign of the determinant. Notice that "P1" is not actually a question

Comment: @Darius For P2, should that say $\det(\boldsymbol{A}^\Sigma_n(x))= \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\det(\boldsymbol{A}^{\color{red}{\delta}}(x))$?

Comment: For Q2: Yes, you are right. For Q1: I am asking if there exists a **unique** solution $A^\delta$ for all matrices $A$, since there can be performed many simple operations that then give the condition, but they have more than one solutions for one specific matrix $A$. I am asking if there is only one operation that can be done on a given matrix.

Comment: Sorry, only one *possible* operation that can be done on a matrix.